# Footer: Typeset by AmS-TeX

Tags: header-footer, amstex

How can I make a document display as a footer the text "Typeset by AmS-TeX"? I'm having trouble finding how to make this. Can you please help?

Comment: Ams-TeX refers to a particular macro package developed for AMS by Michal Spivak. The text "Typeset by AmS-TeX" was automatically inserted when the document used `amsppt.sty` and, if I remember correctly, this could be disabled by saying `\nologo`. What's your setting?

Comment: I tried:\input{amstex}
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  but didn't work

Comment: No, `amsppt.sty` and `amstex.tex` don't go along with LaTeX. What precisely are you trying to do? The "Typeset by AmS-TeX" makes little sense for a document typeset in LaTeX: it would be a lie.

Comment: This might not work, since AMS-TeX is built on plain TeX and might not work with LaTeX at all.

Comment: Could you use `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and then `\cfoot{Typeset by AmS-TeX}`?

Comment: @egreg: just trying to insert that line, it looks nice.

Comment: I never liked it. And it would be a lie, if you don't use AmS-TeX.

Answer (score 4):

Use AMS-TeX and the preprint style `amsppt.sty` and compile with TeX or pdfTeX, not LaTeX.

A minimal working example:

```
\magnification 1300
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\pagewidth{6.5 true in}
\pageheight{9.0 true in}
\topmatter
\title A Test Document \endtitle
\date November 24, 2011\enddate
\endtopmatter
\document
Text
\bye
```

[image: Output, some white space cropped]

Relevant lines in `amsppt.sty`:

```
\def\inslogo@{\insert\copyins{\logo@}}
\def\logo@{\rightline{\eightpoint Typeset by \AmSTeX}}
```

`\inslogo@` is used in `\endtopmatter`, so this is also required.

Comment: How many years! :)