# Tex preamble to produce this output (font, text width, etc.)

Tags: fonts, document-classes, layout

What kind of Tex header / preamble (documentclass, package inclusions, etc.) would produce such a output (font, width of text, etc.) ? [http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/Notes.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eksound/Notes.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like `\documentclass{amsart}` (with default settings).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35968/footer-typeset-by-ams-tex

Comment: Judging from of the footer in the title page of the lecture note, it's probably typeset by tex (not latex) using amsppt.sty as shown in the above link.

Comment: `amsart` is the LaTeX equivalent/successor to `amsppt`.  For all practical purposes, the defaults should (were intended to) be the same.  For the cited document, a new page would have to be specified manually before every section.

Comment: Thanks to all, for the answers.